# Selenium Maven test runs in console but not on Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have deplyed my selenium test on Maven and all neccessary PATHS, JAVA_HOME, MAVEN_HOME have been set correctly . I tested my test using the command (mvn clean test) on CMD and was successful .  However i deployed this on Jenkins and used the same command to invoke test in the same directory . I got the error below

'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have checked all the neccessary system and environmental variables and all seems fine

-

I expect the same test to be executed when i run the  build on Jenkins , This is working on command prompt

Comment: Your Jenkins is not configured correctly or you are not using it correctly...

Comment: In Manage Jenkins/Global Tool Configuration under Maven installations do you have anything there?

Comment: How have you configured you build job? Using pipelines etc. ?

Comment: @gavsyuk. I have it empty for now. I also entered the MAVEN PATH and still same result

Answer (score 0):

If your maven installation is empty then you will not be able to use maven, here is what mine looks like as a reference.

[image]